# Is there any way that we can get Web Deploy to make a backup before deploying?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, microsoft-web-deploy

The Web Deploy tool is great; we use it nearly every day. 
Is there any way that we can get WebDeploy to make a backup before deploying?

[Automating Deployment with Microsoft Web Deploy](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy)